# How should integrate and structure templateHyper folder into existing web project folder?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, bootstrap-5

Where should i integrate and structure 'templateHyper'(Bootstrap template) folder in my web project?

I have been working on a project where i use C#, javascript, html and bootstrap (templateHyper), and i'm looking for the best practice in order to structure my folders, if someone could help me with this, i would appreciate.

Comment: Please follow these instructions - https://themes.getbootstrap.com/guide/#setting-up-local-development

Answer (score 0):

The "templateHyper" folder, containing the Bootstrap template should be integrated into your web project's "static" or "assets" folder. This ensures a clear separation between code and static files. Follow a consistent folder structure, organizing files by type (CSS, JS, images) for easier maintenance and scalability.